# Paypal refund with Security Token through the Payflow API

Tags: paypal

To issue a credit via Payflow Pro the Transaction Type (TRXTYPE) variable should be set to a "C" as shown in the following examples:

To credit the same card used in the ORIGID for the full amount, the following is the request url 
"TRXTYPE=C&TENDER=C&PARTNER=xpartner&VENDOR=xlogin&USER=xlogin&PWD=xpassword&ORIGID=PA0102000000"

If manager account security token setting is set to true and I am sending the security token along with the refund request, should I be sending the below details as well?
PARTNER=xpartner&VENDOR=xlogin&USER=xlogin&PWD=xpassword

If yes, once the secure connection has established why should I need to send this information. Please clarify ?

Answer (score 0):

To refund a transaction there is no need to send any secure token at all. The security settings in manager doesn't apply when it comes to refund .

Comment: If the answer is helpful , accept it as an  swer so tat it will be useful for others .